# Kurdistan vs Iraqi Kurdistan?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We've recently had a bunch of questions about [kurdistan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kurdistan), which is [a bit ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan), although not hugely so since [Iraqi Kurdistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraqi_Kurdistan) (aka Kurdistan Regional Government) is the only 'traveller-relevant' bit (autonomous, has its own immigration and visas, etc).

For clarity, should we retag these as [iraqi-kurdistan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraqi-kurdistan)?

Comment: There's also a province in Iran called Kurdistan, so regardless of political ...stuff, it prevents ambiguity.

Comment: I was just about to hit post on the same thing! I wholeheartedly agree with using [tag:iraqi-kurdistan] for those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you, there is no country with the name (Kurdistan), we should change it to Iraqi Kurdistan.

Comment: There is no country called "air travel" either. Many people feel there is no country called "Israel" or no country called "Palestine". None of that matters because we can make a tag for anything relevant to travellers, not every tag has to be the name of a universally recognized country.

Comment: This is not about how people feel, it's about *what exists*.  Is there an Iraqi Kurdistani government that controls entry to its borders and issues visas?  Yes, in the same way that there's an Israeli and a Northern Cypriot government, so travellers need to know about them and we need tags to organize questions about them.

Comment: Try to avoid strawmen like talking about "what exists" at one point and then about governments in the next point as though they are naturally equated. Kurdistan *exists* too. It is "a roughly defined geo-cultural region wherein the Kurdish people form a prominent majority population, and Kurdish culture, language, and national identity have historically been based." In fact from your words I can't even tell if you are arguing for or against.

Answer (score 2):

As MeNoTalk states, there is no country called Kurdistan. There are however, Kurds, and the Kurdish people, and the Kurdish way of life. The language is, well, I don't know what language or dialect they speak.

However, for what purpose would someone use Kurdistan? There is no people called that. There is no language called that. There is no government of Kurdistan to issue laws or visas. If we were to make Kurdistan a synonym of Iraqi-Kurdistan, Kurds living in that geographical area known as Syria might object (at least once the current conflict is resolved) as might the peoples in Northwestern Iran.

Comment: They speak Kurdish. Well surely some only speak their local national language and surely most are bilingual and surely some only speak Kuridsh. I think there are two major dialects of Kurdish with orthographies and which might be considered "standard", and surely several other dialects.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem.

Tags don't have to be at the country level. Tags don't even have to be for places. They just have to have meaning to some number of travellers.

Just as we have tags like "asia" as well as tags like "china" and "japan" we can have a tag for all of the area that some people refer to as Kurdistan, no matter what current national borders parts of that area fall in. And we can also have tags for the subareas of that larger area for questions that are focussed on the part of Kurdistan within Iraq, the part within Turkey, etc.

Comment: But all the questions asked with that tag so far are specifically about the visa/residency procedures of the (Iraqi) Kurdistan Regional Government, not the Kurdish region/culture/language/... as a whole.

Comment: So thus far there's no need to have both tags, but also no harm done by having both tags as we'll be future-ready when somebody does ask.

Comment: @jpatokal: You inspired me! [Is it currently possible for a traveller to travel directly between the different parts of “Kurdistan” which lie within different countries?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43014)

Comment: Having a single [Kurdistan] tag can lead to misunderstanding, in best cases answers and questions have to provide extra details to clarify confusing things. As of now, there is only one officially recognized Kurdistan, that is iraqi-Kurdistan. If people are asking about culture or language then also a single tag is a bad idea, since Kurds in Iraq speak a different language than the ones in Syria AFAIK.. a single tag is a bad idea..

Comment: I'm not advocating a single tag. I'm advertising whatever tags make sense. As of now there is one for Kurdistan as a whole, "recognized" or not (just like Palestine and Tibet and Israel and Nagorno Karabakh and Abkhazia) and one for Iraqi Kurdistan. I'm not sure who "recognizes" it but I'd be surprised if everybody does. Jeez, we're not "Statehood Recognition Stack Exchange", we're "Travel Stack Exchange", and travellers are among the groups who recognize such a place exists. Misunderstandings we can clear up or retag when they happen, as we do anyway.

Comment: Recognition is irrelevant, what matters is whether they *exist*.  You can deny the recognition of Kosovo/Israel/Iraqi Kurdistan/Indian Kashmir/... all you like, but you're not going to get into any of those unless you play by their governments' rules.

Comment: Here's the thing though, going by what is being suggested, should we not have America, American, United States, North America and Northern America (a synonym of Canada... heh, j/k)... I guess my problem is why go one way or the other...are we limited in the total number of tags we can use? or we just don't want one question per tag?

Comment: @CGCampbell: Exactly! All the arguments against a "Kursistan" tag apply equally against an "air travel" tag where we should instead have "air travel to USA", "air travel to Canada" etc.